# Creating a Book Inventory System in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, inventory, inventory-management

I'm currently in the process of creating a inventory system designed for books and other paper goods. I want to create the website in Ruby on Rails. What I'm looking for is any examples or ideas that can make that happen.

What I need to happen is when this is set up it'll have the books added, with a current count and a few other details(name, date published, etc.). Now when a delivery comes in they can add to the current count. When books are removed they can of course subtract that from the total. Love all this to be seemless if possible. The more its user friendly the better.

Also when books are reaching a low stock a warning will be shown. Also a list of books alphabetically with all the details and so forth.

I'm at a loss on how exactly to do this efficiently, I'm fairly new to Ruby on Rails but very familiar with HTML, PHP, CSS and so those cause no problems.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, Nanosmo! This is a very general question, and we prefer more focused, specific ones. I suggest that you take a shot, make an attempt, and come back with specific issues.

Comment: It looks like you need to learn a few things about Rails first. Try reading this book: http://pragprog.com/book/rails4/agile-web-development-with-rails. I'm pretty sure you'll get the idea after finishing that book.

Comment: Welcome to the Rails Community! A good introduction to rails is imho written by Michael Hartl (http://ruby.railstutorial.org/).
And of course, there is (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/), which is very detailed, but can be a bit overwhelming sometimes. Still a good reference and you can learn a lot from it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm also in a phase were I want to build a Book Inventory System using Ruby (because of it great XML support). In my quick research these are some interesting links:

[Beginning Ruby on Rails E-Commerce: From Novice to Professional](http://books.google.be/books?id=o0JuxK5_1esC&pg=PA59&lpg=PA59&dq=book%20inventory%20ruby&source=bl&ots=rnhYJzefUZ&sig=OGlVlWO9wYo7gxy-HmxVQZIEeSU&hl=en&sa=X&ei=NLgBUfr6M_CY0QWBooH4Bw&ved=0CFMQ6AEwBQ#v=onepage&q=book%20inventory%20ruby&f=false)
And also a github project:
[Sample project](https://github.com/jasondelponte/Ruby-Book-Inventory)